# Non-repeating permutations of string in lexicographical order

Tags: c, string, algorithm, permutation

I was reading about the generation of permutations of a string when I saw [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lexicographic-permutations-of-string/). The following is the code mentioned in the post:

```c
// Program to print all permutations of a string in sorted order.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Following function is needed for library function qsort(). Refer
   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/ */
int compare (const void *a, const void * b)
{  return ( *(char *)a - *(char *)b ); }

// A utility function two swap two characters a and b
void swap (char* a, char* b)
{
    char t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

// This function finds the index of the smallest character
// which is greater than 'first' and is present in str[l..h]
int findCeil (char str[], char first, int l, int h)
{
    // initialize index of ceiling element
    int ceilIndex = l;

    // Now iterate through rest of the elements and find
    // the smallest character greater than 'first'
    for (int i = l+1; i <= h; i++)
      if (str[i] > first && str[i] < str[ceilIndex])
            ceilIndex = i;

    return ceilIndex;
}

// Print all permutations of str in sorted order
void sortedPermutations ( char str[] )
{
    // Get size of string
    int size = strlen(str);

    // Sort the string in increasing order
    qsort( str, size, sizeof( str[0] ), compare );

    // Print permutations one by one
    bool isFinished = false;
    while ( ! isFinished )
    {
        // print this permutation
        printf ("%s \n", str);

        // Find the rightmost character which is smaller than its next
        // character. Let us call it 'first char'
        int i;
        for ( i = size - 2; i >= 0; --i )
           if (str[i] < str[i+1])
              break;

        // If there is no such chracter, all are sorted in decreasing order,
        // means we just printed the last permutation and we are done.
        if ( i == -1 )
            isFinished = true;
        else
        {
            // Find the ceil of 'first char' in right of first character.
            // Ceil of a character is the smallest character greater than it
            int ceilIndex = findCeil( str, str[i], i + 1, size - 1 );

            // Swap first and second characters
            swap( &str[i], &str[ceilIndex] );

            // Sort the string on right of 'first char'
            qsort( str + i + 1, size - i - 1, sizeof(str[0]), compare );
        }
    }
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    char str[] = "ABCD";
    sortedPermutations( str );
    return 0;
}
```

But this code cannot handle cases when string has repeated alphabets (eg. abca) and thus duplicate permutations are generated.

How can we change this algorithm to generate non-repeating permutations in lexicographical order. Or is there any other method to do so?

Comment: What do you consider the valid permutations on the string `abca`?

Comment: Have you tried running this code with duplicates?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError...aabc,aacb,abac,abca,.... and others... total 12

Comment: I would think a solution could be had than sorts the string _once_ and then generates the permutations.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat...i hadn't ...although I have now and it works and now it seems quite logical. If strings are being printed in lexicographical order, duplicates can be printed only consecutively and this algorithm ensures that that doesn't happen...thanks anyways...

Answer (score 0):

There are no repeated alphabets in your example, just characters in the input alphabet.

I won't give you ready code but just an idea how to handle duplicates. It is simple and might be not most effective, but it is not bad and it will make the code work.

Instead of plainly printing the permutation, you can store it in a container that will handle duplicates.

IMO a lexicographic tree would be good for this purpose. Putting an element of size `N` into it takes `O(N)`, so it actually do not worsen the time complexity in terms of Big-Oh  ( as printing also takes O(N) such as any kind of `store` operation ). You can count dupes there or just do nothing if the element exists.

Then you can traverse the tree and print non duplicated entries.

Answer (score 0):

After David Eisenstat pointed it out in the comments, I ran the program and found that it didn't print duplicates. I had assumed certain problems which this code would face which in reality it doesn't.

My explanation on why the code works is:-

If strings are being printed in lexicographical order by the algorithm, duplicates can be printed only consecutively and if you dry run this algorithm, you can see that it doesn't print the same string consecutively. And if the duplicate string wasn't printed just after the original, it can't be printed anywhere else lest the lexicographical error should be broken